# Room LiveData Problem When App First Installed

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I'm developing an app as a training. Currently It does api call and load data to Room if internet connection available and at the same time UI shows data from Room. It works fine after first boot but when I install it to a new device-emulator etc. or re-install it. It doesn't show data at the first boot but if I close it and open again. It keeps working fine. How do i solve this ?
Here is my code:

**CityDao**

```
  interface CityDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun addCity(cityRm: CityRm)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM city_table ORDER BY cId ASC")
    suspend fun readAllCities(): List<CityRm>
}
```

**CityRoomRepository**

```
   class CityRoomRepository(private val cityDao: CityDao) {

    suspend fun readAllCities(): List<CityRm> {
        return cityDao.readAllCities()
    }

    suspend fun addCity(cityRm: CityRm) {
        cityDao.addCity(cityRm)
    }

}
```

**CityModelView**

```
class   CityRmViewModel (application: Application):AndroidViewModel(application) {

    val allCities = MutableLiveData<List<CityRm>>()
    private val cityDao = EventsDatabase.getEventsDatabase(application).cityDao()
    private val eventDao = EventsDatabase.getEventsDatabase(application).eventDao()
    private val cityRoomRepository: CityRoomRepository = CityRoomRepository(cityDao)
    private val cityRepository: CityRepository = CityRepository()
    private val eventRepository: EventListRepository = EventListRepository()
    private val eventRoomRepository: EventsRoomRepository = EventsRoomRepository(eventDao)

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch(Main) {
            val cities = cityRoomRepository.readAllCities()
            allCities.value = cities
        }
        viewModelScope.launch(IO) {
            try {
                if (InternetConnectionCheck(application)) {
                    callCityApi(cityRepository, cityRoomRepository)
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("internet connection check error ", e.toString())
            }
        }
        viewModelScope.launch(IO) {
            try {
                if (InternetConnectionCheck(application)) {
                    callEventApi(eventRepository, eventRoomRepository)
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("internet connection check error ", e.toString())
            }
        }
    }

    suspend fun loadData() {
        val cities = cityRoomRepository.readAllCities()
        allCities.value = cities
    }
    
}
```

**City Fragment**

```
class citySelectionPage : Fragment() {

    lateinit var cityViewModel: CityRmViewModel
    private val cityAdapter = cityScPageAdapter(arrayListOf())
    
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_city_selection_page, container, false)

        cityViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(CityRmViewModel::class.java)
        lifecycleScope.launch(Main) {
            cityViewModel.loadData()
        }

        val recyclerView = view.cityPageRecycler
        recyclerView.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
            adapter = cityAdapter
        }

        observeViewModel()
        return view
    }

    fun observeViewModel(){
        cityViewModel.allCities.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { cities ->
            cities?.let {
                cityAdapter.updateCities(it)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**City Adapter**

```
class cityScPageAdapter(var myCities: ArrayList<CityRm>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<cityScPageAdapter.cityScPageViewHolder>() {


    fun updateCities(newCities: List<CityRm>) {
        myCities.clear()
        myCities.addAll(newCities)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): cityScPageViewHolder {
        return cityScPageViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_cities, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: cityScPageViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            SingletonCityID.cityID = myCities[position].cId
            val action = citySelectionPageDirections.goToEventListPage()
            Navigation.findNavController(it).navigate(action)
        }
        holder.bind(myCities[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        Log.d("live data size",myCities.size.toString())
        return myCities.size
    }

    class cityScPageViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){

        private val cityName = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.cityName)

        fun bind(myCity: CityRm) {
            cityName.text = myCity.name
        }
    }

}
```

Edit: Error when i used LiveData<List> instead of List, also get the same errorlog if I try it with MutableLiveData (For CityRm, Dao and Repository)

Comment: Can we see your adapter code? If you debug does this line get hit `cityAdapter.updateCities(it)`?

Comment: @DavidKroukamp I've added adapter code and I've tried debugging, it hits the line but "it" argument is "0"

Answer (score 0):

@fatihberatcan It is empty in the first launch because of the following reason. Since you're loading city from the database, in the first launch it'll not be there. There are no cities in the database yet. You calls city API and it stores the same in the database, but you wouldn't get any event for this. In other word your fragment/UI is unaware that city list is now in the database. You need to use some reactive way like Livedata as David Kroukamp mentioned, so that you'll get notified whenever data changes.

Like you mentioned, next time or on next launch of the app, city list is now there in the database, therefore you're seeing it on the screen.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I've thought that and tried before but livedata or mutablelivedata both gave me kapt errors. public abstract java.lang.Object readAllCities(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()" this is one of them. If you want I can edit my question and give all error log. Finally I think reading from DB after a bit delay would work but IDK that well coroutines

Comment: @fatihberatcan for that you can ask a separate question. I guess you're using wrong NOTNULL annotation.

Comment: @fatihberatcan Or you can edit your question to include your problem with the error log

Comment: I've added ErrorLogs. Actually It gives me these errors while building the app. There is nothing in Logcat because it's not even building with these changes